# Extract UTM parameters in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, utm-tracking

I need to extract UTM parameters in Google Sheets and I have, I believe, a simple question.

I would like to extract the value associated to the `utm_campaign` in column A to column B:

[image: Example]

If possible, I would like to keep the opportunity to do an Arrayformula for all the lines in column A and avoid using a script to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "utm_campaign"":""(\d+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found an answer by myself!
Using the formula below works in that case:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "utm_campaign"":""([^""]+)""")))
```